# Find a word in a string in R

Tags: r, string

I am looking for a command that solves the following task. So I have a vector containing urls as strings like:

```
urls <- c("https//:www.I-like.apples/hello.com",
          "https//:www.I-eat-apples-every-day.com",
          "https//:www.apples-are-red.com")
```

I need a command that assign 0 if the string doesn't contain the word `apples` and 1 if it does. These 0sand 1s will be stored in another vector of the same legth of the string vector.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `grepl` to return a logical vector and convert to binary with `+`

```
v2 <-  +(grepl("apples", urls))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/).

```
library(stringr)

new_vector <- ifelse(str_detect(urls, "apples"), 1, 0)

new_vector
# [1] 1 1 1
```